# ASP.NET MCV application sends GET request after POST

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have ASP.NET MVC application which populates datatable via POST request.

I have really strange issue: sometimes application sends same GET request as POST which causes error to be logged into database via ELMAH.

This is from IIS log:

`2014-10-09 10:47:28 10.74.132.4 POST /assignments/searchassignments - 80 danilo 95.180.110.178 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+rv:32.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/32.0 200 0 0 736`

`2014-10-09 10:47:28 10.74.132.4 GET /assignments/searchassignments - 80 danilo 95.180.110.178 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+rv:32.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/32.0 302 0 0 708`

First request is valid, but the second request is not, because there is no `SearchAssignments` action which accepts GET.

POST REQUEST:

```
$.ajax({
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "POST",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": function (json)
                {
                    fnCallback(json);
                },
                "error": function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    nwa.util.showUnhandledError();
                }
            });
```

Comment: What are you returning from your searchassignments controller action?

Comment: Action returns JSON. Also, when I use Firebug to see which requests does application send, there is no GET requst in list, only POST

Comment: Does it also behave the same in Chrome and IE? Also can you show how form is submitted? jquery submit ?

Comment: Yes. Application caught errors from all browsers. But this issue does not happen always, only sometimes

Comment: How is this POST being created? Via Ajax? Can you post some code?

Comment: Whats does the fnCallback(json) do?

Comment: Looks like a post from datatable. Can you try to return false from the function you call/trigger ajax post.

Comment: It is not case only with database. I have simple POST when user change value in dropdown and sometimes, application sends GET request for this also